# Cannot understand where this 'Invalid BigNumber' error comes from?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, ethers.js

I am working on a lottery dapp and I am facing a problem with deploying my contract on local network.

I do not have big experience debugging code like this and I am a bit lost.

I can clearly see from the error log that the problem is about a big number value, but I cannot understand where that could be in my code since I do not get any clear explanation from the error per se.

Any ideas?

Here is the code deployed:

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("2")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionRepsonse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionRepsonse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }

    const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
    const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
    const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
    const keepersUpdateInterval = networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"]

    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        entranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callbackGasLimit,
        keepersUpdateInterval,
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, args)
    }
    log("----------------------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]
```

Here is the error log:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp> yarn hardhat deploy
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
$ "C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\.bin\hardhat" deploy
Nothing to compile
Local network detected! Deploying mocks...
deploying "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock" (tx: 0xcc454aa73563f7b97237e5ab1ed0859f0eaeea6abea666542e0455b43d97ace6)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 2526713 gas
Mocks Deployed!
----------------------------------------------------------
You are deploying to a local network, you'll need a local network running to interact
Please run `yarn hardhat console --network localhost` to interact with the deployed smart contracts!
----------------------------------------------------------
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\deploy\01- deploy-raffle.js:
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:285:21)
    at Function.BigNumber.from (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\bignumber\src.ts\bignumber.ts:289:23)
    at NumberCoder.encode (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\number.ts:25:27)
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:71:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:54:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\tuple.ts:54:20)
    at AbiCoder.encode (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\abi-coder.ts:111:15)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Blockchain\Ethereum\Smart-Lottery dApp\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:584:32)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error was due to the wrong positioning of the arguments in args array.

You should follow the same order on deploy.js file as the one you followed when creating the raffle.sol file.